# Can I execute a T-SQL query to determine maximum data size for a SQL Server Express instance?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-express

The original version of SQL Server Express had a fixed database size limit of 4GB. With 2008 R2 this has increased to 10GB.

Our original code executed `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')`, then looked for the string "Express" to identify an express edition. We then assumed a limit of 4GB. Obviously this broke when 2008 R2 came out. I want to avoid using the presence of "Express" or "Express R2" to then derive a limit of 4GB or 10GB. This would fails if/when Microsoft bring out an "R3" version with some arbitrary new limit.

Is there some way to programatically determine (i.e. by executing a T-SQL query) the current size limit?

Comment: It would be surprising if such a thing did exist - it would be either a pointless feature in higher editions of the product, or would be an extra feature they'd have to add to Express, for very little value. I'd a) switch to the EngineEdition property, so you can get rid of your string comparison, and b) either impose a strict limit of 4GB (how are you using this information?), or just write enough code for today to distinguish pre-SQL2008 R2 and SQL2008 R2 or later, with the limits you know today.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - While it's of no use for more advanced editions, our application requires users to install their own local database (on SQL Server Express, because it's free!). It's a nice feature to be able to give them an indication that they are running short of space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are restoring a backup larger than 4GB on SQL Server 2005 Express Edition, you will get this error:

CREATE DATABASE or ALTER DATABASE failed because the
resulting cumulative database size would exceed your licensed
limit of 4096 MB per database.

In case you have got an existing database in SQL Server 2005 Express Edition and suddendly grows beyond 4GB, you will get this error:

Could not allocate a new page for database ‘YourDatabaseName’ because of insufficient disk space in filegroup ‘YourFilegroup’. Create the necessary space by dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.

So the answer is NO. Database size limit parameter is defined in sqlservr.exe.
Unless you can recompile original code there is no way you can get it via TSQL.

Inspired by @Kevin Ross and @Damien_The_Unbeliever suggestions:

```
SELECT

CASE

WHEN SERVERPROPERTY ('EngineEdition') = 4 -- 4 = Express Edition

THEN

CASE

WHEN (SELECT max_size FROM sys.database_files WHERE file_id =1)=-1

THEN

CASE

WHEN CONVERT(REAL,CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')), 1, CHARINDEX('.', CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')))-1))) < 10.5 -- Not SQL Server R2

THEN

'You have got '

+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(38), (SELECT 4096-size/128 FROM sys.database_files WHERE file_id =1))

+' Mb '

+'('

+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(38), CONVERT(int, 100*CONVERT(float, (SELECT 4096 - size/128 FROM sys.database_files WHERE file_id =1))

/
4096))

+ '%) available.'

+ ' You may increase your database size up to 4Gb.'

ELSE -- You have got SQL Server R2

'You have got '

+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(38), (SELECT 10240-size/128 FROM sys.database_files WHERE file_id =1))

+' Mb'

+'('

+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(38), CONVERT(int, 100*CONVERT(float, (SELECT 10240 - size/128 FROM sys.database_files WHERE file_id =1))

/
10240))

+ '%) available.'

+ ' You may increase your database size up to 10Gb.'

END

ELSE

CASE

WHEN CONVERT(REAL,CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')), 1, CHARINDEX('.', CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')))-1))) < 10.5 -- Not SQL Server R2

THEN

'You have got '

+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(38), (SELECT max_size - size FROM sys.database_files WHERE file_id =1)/128)

+' Mb left out of '

+' Mb ('

+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(38), CONVERT(int, 100*CONVERT(float, (SELECT max_size - size FROM sys.database_files WHERE file_id =1))

/
CONVERT(float,(SELECT max_size FROM sys.database_files WHERE file_id =1))))

+ '%).'

+ ' You may increase your database size up to 4Gb.'

ELSE -- You have got SQL Server R2

'You have got '

+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(38), (SELECT max_size - size FROM sys.database_files WHERE file_id =1)/128)

+' Mb left out of '

+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(38), (SELECT max_size FROM sys.database_files WHERE file_id =1)/128)

+' Mb ('

+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(38), CONVERT(int, 100*CONVERT(float, (SELECT max_size - size FROM sys.database_files WHERE file_id =1))

/
CONVERT(float,(SELECT max_size FROM sys.database_files WHERE file_id =1))))

+ '%).'

+ ' You may increase your database size up to 10Gb.'

END

END

ELSE -- Congratulations! You have got something better than Express Edition!

CASE

WHEN (SELECT max_size FROM sys.database_files WHERE file_id =1)=-1

THEN

'Main file will grow until the disk is full.'

ELSE

'You have got '

+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(38), (SELECT max_size - size FROM sys.database_files WHERE file_id =1)/128)

+' Mb left out of '

+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(38), (SELECT max_size FROM sys.database_files WHERE file_id =1)/128)

+' Mb ('

+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(38), CONVERT(int, 100*CONVERT(float, (SELECT max_size - size FROM sys.database_files WHERE file_id =1))

/
CONVERT(float,(SELECT max_size FROM sys.database_files WHERE file_id =1))))

+ '%)'

END

END

AS
Database_Info
```

Obviously I haven't had a chance to check it on SQL Server 2005-2008-R2.

Comment: can you point me at an article that confirms that the limit is embedded in sqlservr.exe? See my comment on the question explaining why it would be useful to know the size limit.

Comment: Microsoft developers would know about it. Because of the sensitive issue of licensing I personally don’t think you will find anything on the internet. Any text editor will show you that aforementioned error messages embedded in sqlservr.exe .

Comment: Thanks for the input. Your SQL may prove useful to someone else, but it doesn't exactly fulfil my requirement. I'm accepting this as the answer because it seems, as you first suggested, that what I originally wanted in not possible. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont have anything other than 2008R2 Express to test this against but would something like this work?

```
SELECT 
case when SERVERPROPERTY ('EngineEdition')=4 THEN
     CASE WHEN convert(real,convert(varchar(5),SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'))) <10.5 THEN 
     '4Gb Limit' 
     ELSE '10Gb Limit' end
     else 'no limit' end as Size_Limit
```

This first checks to see if it is an express edition, if it is not then it returns 'No Limit' if it is express it checks the version number, if it is less than 10.5 (pre 2008R2) then it returns 4Gb, it is is greater than or equal to 10.5 then it displays 10Gb

Comment: As I said in my comment to the question, a more robust check would use the EngineEdition property rather than the Edition property

Comment: @Damien_The_Ungeliever Good shout, I have changed my code sample to get rid of the string function and replace it with the EngineEdition check.

Comment: Unfortunately your answer doesn't really provide what I asked i.e. a solution that is future proof (if MS put out a new Express version with an increased limit). The other answer from Pavel may be correct - maybe I just have to live with the limitation.