# SQL Express Database size limit via query

Tags: sql

We know the max size of SQL data files allowed in SQL express editions are 2 GB, 4 GB , 10 GB for SQL 2000, 2005, 2008 express respectively.

Is there any way we could see the max size of the database allowed via SQL query?

Comment: i'll be first one to accept answers if it's helpful, and solves problem. Thanks

Comment: yes thanks, just wanted to make sure a thing that is not properly an answer should not be marked an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I execute a T-SQL query to determine maximum data size for a SQL Server Express instance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018057/can-i-execute-a-t-sql-query-to-determine-maximum-data-size-for-a-sql-server-expre)

Comment: thanks Damien_The_Unbeliever,we do it differently in my application , but your answer is cool in the cited link , that's useful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Max size is exactly that. I'm not aware of any query you can run to get this information directly.

You could get the SQL Server version:

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

and infer from that.

Comment: That's known, but we need where exact the database size is maintained? or is there no other way to get it from query?

Comment: @jebina: not that I'm aware of.